# Register page else/if

Tags: java

I am very new to java and need some help. I would like to add a function to this register page where users cannot leave their password and username fields blank. I would very much appreciate it if you could type the lines of code as it would be easier for me to visualize.

I have tried implementing else if to this page but it doesn't work and there is no error as well, so i removed those codes. Those codes does not appear in the lines of code i have shown here.Cheers

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mTextUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_username);
    mTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_password);
    mTextCnfPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_cnf_password);
    mButtonRegister = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton_register);
    mTextViewLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_login);
    mTextViewLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent LoginIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginPageActivity.class);
            startActivity(LoginIntent);
        }
    });

    mButtonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String user = mTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            String pwd = mTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            String cnf_pwd = mTextCnfPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if(pwd.equals(cnf_pwd)) {
                Long val = db.adduser(user,pwd);
                if(val > 0){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Successfully Registered.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent movetoLogin = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginPageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(movetoLogin);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registration Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Those passwords didn't match.Try Again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us the code that produces the error, and provide us with the error for further assistance. As it stands there is no shown implementation that checks for an empty username/password field in this code, and in my opinion it should not require an else if from the looks of it based on where I would implement it.

Comment: Hey, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We can help if you are facing some problem, but in your case, you should look up validation tutorial for android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the required attribute in html to avid those fields being left blanked.If you use this then you will not need a code to handle blank fields but it will control that situation in the frontend itself.
Refer here how to use it : [required attribute](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-required-attribute/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried make a length comparisson ?

Change this line: `if(pwd.equals(cnf_pwd)) {` to

```
if(pwd.length() > 0 && user.length() > 0 && pwd.equals(cnf_pwd)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make it that complicated. After declaring strings,You can use

```
if(pwd.isEmpty() || user.isEmpty() )
{
Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Enter Username and Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
  if{pwd.equals(cnf_pwd)) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Successfully Registered.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent movetoLogin = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginPageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(movetoLogin);
    }
  else
    {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Make sure Password Entered is same",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not all on same if ? and put on else print like the user or password are empty or the password is not same in 2 fields.

Comment: @deoncagadoes that can be done but this way the user will know what went wrong.